# Send post via CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

After sending POST to webmoney merchant, appear error:

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> There is a problem with the page you are looking for and it cannot be
>   displayed. This error can occur if you are trying to display an HTML
>   page that resides in a directory that is configured to allow Execute
>   or Script permissions only. Please try the following:
>
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe this directory
>   should allow read access. HTTP Error 403.2 - Forbidden: Read access is
>   denied. Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
>   for the words HTTP and 403. Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS
>   Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Using Virtual
>   Directories, Changing Default Web Site Settings, and About Custom
>   Error Messages.

CODE:

```
$param = array(
    'LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT' => '2',
    'LMI_PAYMENT_DESC' => 'Return a debt by invoice',
    'LMI_PAYMENT_NO' => rand(0, 9999),
    'LMI_PAYEE_PURSE' => 'Z401998872708',
    'LMI_SIM_MODE' => '0',
);

//
$url = "https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp";
$post = "LMI_PAYEE_PURSE=Z401998872708&LMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT=1&LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=Return a debt by invoice";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
$referer = "https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/payment.asp";
$pathCerts="/mnt/d/web/test/WMunited.cer";
//
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $pathCerts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookies.txt');//куки сохранить
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookies.txt');
//  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ ,);
//  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ ,);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $str = str_replace ("<head>","<head><base href = 'https://merchant.webmoney.ru/lmi/'>", $result);
```